# Tensordot confusion

Tags: numpy

I might be misundertanding `tensordor`. I am trying to do the following partial contraction:

```
c(e,q,i,j) = a(e,q,i,j,k,l) * b(e,q,l,k)
```

Using

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(1*4*2*2*2*2).reshape(1,4,2,2,2,2)
b = np.random.random(1*4*2*2).reshape(1,4,2,2)

c = np.tensordot(a,b,axes=([5,2],[4,3]))
```

But it is giving me the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in tensordot(a, b, axes)
   1282     else:
   1283         for k in range(na):
-> 1284             if as_[axes_a[k]] != bs[axes_b[k]]:
   1285                 equal = False
   1286                 break

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: `[4,3]` is for `b` and it dosn't have `4`.

Comment: @Divakar I see, so it should be `c = np.tensordot(a,b,axes=([5,4],[2,3]))`? But that doesn't work either, as the output shape is `(1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 4)` while it should be `(1, 4, 2, 2)`.

Comment: It seems you are looking to keep few axes aligned. So, look for einsum/matmul.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. So such an operation is completely impossible with `tensordot`?

Comment: `tensordot` reduces the calculation to a `dot` using a combination of reshape and transpose.  So like `dot` it can't just pass the `e,q` dimensions through unchanged.  `matmul` was created to handle leading dimensions in the way that you want.

Comment: @hpaulj That makes it clear, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking to keep few of the axes aligned. As such, `tensordot` won't work *directly*. Instead, we can use `np.einsum` -

```
np.einsum('ijklmn,ijnm->ijkl',a,b)
```